# tensorflow differentiate only element of vector

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am to understand how tensorflow differentiation behaves when applied on elements of vector.
Here is my code

```
w=tf.Variable([[1.0,2.3],[4.5,6.7]],dtype=tf.float32)
x=tf.constant([[1.2],[2.3]],dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y=tf.matmul(w,x)
d=tape.gradient(y[0],w)
```

**y** is **2x1** tensor. When differentiate **y[0]** w.r.t w i.e a single element of **y** I get **None**.
**d** is None here.
I can't understand this behavior. **y[0]** is depended on **w** ,Why still I'm getting **None**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting none because accessing a sub element of a tensor is actually an operation that needs to be done inside the `tf.GradientTape` context. Otherwise, the tape does not know the history that lead to that variable.

Your example is akin to doing this:

```
w=tf.Variable([[1.0,2.3],[4.5,6.7]],dtype=tf.float32)
x=tf.constant([[1.2],[2.3]],dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y=tf.matmul(w,x)
d=tape.gradient(y+2,w)
```

The tape did not watch the operation `y+2`, so the gradient cannot be calculated.

To get the gradient of only one element, you need to explicitly get that element in the tape's context:

```
w=tf.Variable([[1.0,2.3],[4.5,6.7]],dtype=tf.float32)
x=tf.constant([[1.2],[2.3]],dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    y=tf.matmul(w,x)
    y0 = y[0]
d=tape.gradient(y0,w)
```

And then, you get the gradient of `y[0]` w.r.t `w`:

```
>>> d
<tf.Tensor: shape=(2, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[1.2, 2.3],
       [0. , 0. ]], dtype=float32)>
```